# Epimorphisms $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ are split

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Consider the additive group of integer sequences $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Why does every epimorphism of groups $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ split? $(\star)$

Actually this claim is equivalent to the [Whitehead problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_problem) for countable abelian groups:

"$\Rightarrow$": Recall [Specker's result](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-9259-9_5) which states that $\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{N})} \to \hom(\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}},\mathbb{Z})$, $e_i \mapsto \mathrm{pr}_i$ is an isomorphism, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ is reflexive. Now assume that $A$ is countable and $\mathrm{Ext}^1(A,\mathbb{Z})=0$. Choose a presentation $0 \to P \to Q \to A \to 0$ with free abelian groups $P,Q$, w.l.o.g. of rank $\aleph_0$. By assumption $Q^* \to P^*$ is an epi, hence splits. Since $P,Q$ are reflexive, then also $P \to Q$ splits, and $A$ is free.

"$\Leftarrow$": If $f : \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is an epimorphism, then $f^* : \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ is a monomorphism, the cokernel $A$ of $f^*$ is countable and satisfies $\mathrm{Ext}^1(A,\mathbb{Z})=0$, since $f^{**} \cong f$ is epi. Hence $A$ is free, which implies that $f^*$ splits and therefore also $f^{**} \cong f$ splits. $~\square$

The countable Whitehead problem was proved by [Stein](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02054949) in 1950. He used injective resolutions, i.e. $\mathrm{Ext}^1(A,\mathbb{Z}) = \mathrm{coker}(\hom(A,\mathbb{Q}) \to \hom(A,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}))$. In particular, $(\star)$ is true. On the other hand, the equivalence above suggests an alternative proof of the countable Whitehead problem. Therefore my question is: Is there a direct proof for $(\star)$?

By Specker's result an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ corresponds to an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$, and therefore to a column-finite matrix. But I don't know how to characterize surjectivity. And this is where I get stuck.

Comment: Do you happen to know it's true?

Comment: @Fernando: The Whitehead problem was proved for countable groups. Martin is merely trying an equivalent approach in proving it.

Comment: @Asaf, I'm talking about the question, not about Whitehead's problem.

Comment: @Fernando: Yeah, it just occurred to me. Perhaps it's time to go to sleep... :-P

Comment: My question is *equivalent* to the Whitehead problem for countable abelian groups.

Comment: Martin, why is it so?

Comment: @Fernando: If $P\to Q$ is not mono, then there is a non-zero map $\mathbb{Z}\to P$ such that the composition $\mathbb{Z}\to P\to Q$ is zero. Dualizing, there is a non-zero map $P^*\to\mathbb{Z}$ such that the composition $Q^*\to P^*\to\mathbb{Z}$ is zero, and so $Q^*\to P^*$ is not epi. So every epi $Q^*\to P^*$ comes from a free presentation of some Whitehead group.

Comment: You're asking why $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is *Hopfian*.  One proof is to apply Mal'cev's theorem, which asserts that finitely generated, residually finite groups are Hopfian.

Comment: @HJRW: My question deals with $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ (which, of course, is not Hopfian) and doesn't have to do with the Hopfian property.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg - apologies - I misread $\mathbb{N}$ for $N$!

Comment: In view of @HJRW comment I cannot resist but mentioning that this is one more reason not to rely that much on formulas and formatting details but to describe things verbally if possible. Not sure if this was the case here, but on a mobile device I use that renders MathJax well in general mathbb does not display as such but in a 'normal' font.

Comment: Have you seen the proof of Stein's theorem in Griffith's book on Infinite Abelian Groups? It uses the exact sequence $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\hat{\mathbb{Z}}\rightarrow D\rightarrow0$, where $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $D$ is the resulting (divisible) quotient.  Applying the $Hom$ functor gives $0\rightarrow Hom(A,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow Hom(A,\hat{\mathbb{Z}})\rightarrow Hom(A,D)\rightarrow0$. Now $Hom(A,D)$ is (non-trivial) divisible - because $D$ is divisible - and $Hom(A,\hat{\mathbb{Z}})$ is reduced - because $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is reduced. Thus...

Comment: ... $Hom(A,\mathbb{Z})$ is non-trivial, and so there is a surjection from $A$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, which implies $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus B$.  If one assumes $A$ was finite rank, induction shows $A$ is free.  Thus in a Whitehead group, subgroups of finite rank are free.  By a (fairly easy) theorem of Pontraygin, this implies countable subgroups are free, which is what Stein really proved.

Answer (score 4):

I'll start by describing the notation that I'll use.

I'll think of elements of $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ as infinite column vectors
$${\bf x}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\x_1\\x_2\\\vdots
\end{pmatrix}$$
of integers, with rows indexed by $\mathbb{N}$.

The $i$th "unit vector" will be denoted by ${\bf e(i)}$. I.e., $e(i)_i=1$ and $e(i)_j=0$ for $j\neq i$.

As described in the question, Specker's result implies that endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ are of the form ${\bf x}\mapsto A{\bf x}$ where
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00}&a_{01}&a_{02}&\cdots\\
a_{10}&a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots\\
a_{20}&a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$
is an infinite matrix of integers, with rows and columns indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, that is row-finite (i.e., each row has only finitely many non-zero entries).

Now suppose that $\alpha:\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ is a surjective group homomorphism, given by a row-finite matrix $A$.

To prove that $\alpha$ is split, we need to find a right inverse. In fact,  it suffices to find another row-finite matrix $B$ such that $AB$ is lower unitriangular (i.e., diagonal entries are all $1$ and entries above the diagonal are all $0$), since such a matrix is invertible.

Fix $n\geq0$, and decompose $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}=G_n\oplus H_n$, where $G_n\cong\mathbb{Z}^n$ is the subgroup consisting of those ${\bf a}$ with $a_i=0$ for $i\geq n$, and $H_n\cong\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ is the subgroup consisting of those ${\bf a}$ with $a_i=0$ for $i<n$.

Since $\alpha$ is surjective, $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}=\alpha\left(G_n\right)+\alpha\left(H_n\right)$.

Consider the quotient maps 
$$\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\stackrel{\theta}{\to} \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}/\alpha\left(H_n\right)\stackrel{\varphi}{\to} \left(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}/\alpha\left(H_n\right)\right)/T\left(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}/\alpha\left(H_n\right)\right),$$ 
where $T(X)$ denotes the torsion subgroup of an abelian group $X$.

Since $\left(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}/\alpha\left(H_n\right)\right)/T\left(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}/\alpha\left(H_n\right)\right)$ is a finite rank free abelian group, using Specker's result again implies that $\varphi\theta({\bf e(i)})=0$, or equivalently $\theta({\bf e(i)})\in T\left(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}/\alpha\left(H_n\right)\right)$, for all but finitely many $i$.

Since $T\left(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}/\alpha\left(H_n\right)\right)$ is finite, for all but finitely many $i$ with $\theta({\bf e(i)})\in T\left(\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}/\alpha\left(H_n\right)\right)$, there is $i'>i$ with $\theta({\bf e(i')})=\theta({\bf e(i)})$, or equivalently ${\bf e(i)}-{\bf e(i')}\in\alpha(H_n)$.

So we can choose a sequence $0=t_0<t_1<t_2<\dots$ of integers such that for every $i\geq t_n$ there is some $i'>i$ and some ${\bf b(i)}\in H(n)$ with ${\bf e(i)}-{\bf e(i')}=\alpha\left({\bf b(i)}\right)$. For each $i$, do this with the largest $n$ such that $i\geq t_n$, and let $B$ be the matrix whose $i$th column is ${\bf b(i)}$.

Then $B$ is row-finite, and $AB$ is lower unitriangular.